# Subclass of View constructor not being called

Tags: android, constructor, view, subclass

I'm subclassing Android's view class, but whenever I make an instance of the view from another class, the constructor never gets called (or so it seems). I've implemented both `public myclass (Context context)` and `public myclass (Context context, AttributeSet, attrs)`

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to override onDraw and onMeasure?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: How are you inflating your view? XML or java code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what your code is so I'll just show you a Draw that worked for me

```
    class DrawOnTop extends View { 
    public DrawOnTop(Context context) { 
            super(context); 
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    } 
    @Override 
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
            // TODO this is where stuff is drawn.

    }
```

}